# Using values from an excel file in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

am ne in JS
I have several questions:

The code below, it is opening/extracting the information from XLS properly
I would like:

1. How can I make that I should be able to access *results* after having finised *readXlsxFile * procedure?
2. I would like to make the computer to wait 1 second after consoling each line.
   I was not able to get it to work
3. One of my attempts was readXlsx().then(()=>{})   but it also gave me an error. Why?

```
const readXlsxFile = require("read-excel-file/node");
const fs = require('fs')
// const results = [];
var results = [];
let maxRow

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

function readXlsx() {
  
  readXlsxFile('./myfile.xlsx')
    .then((rows) => {
      console.log("Wait!!")
      results.push(rows)    // Push the complete result into array

      // console.log(results)

      var maxRow = rows.length
      // nRow = 0 Will be the title. WILL NOT CONSOLE
      for (var nRow  = 1; nRow<maxRow-1; nRow++) {
        if (nRow <= 10) {
          console.log(nRow)
          console.log(results[0][nRow][0])
          console.log(results[0][nRow][1])
          console.log(results[0][nRow][2])
          console.log('---')
        }
        // .then(()=>{sleep(500)})      
      }

      return Promise.resolve("Success")
  })

}

function testSleep() {
    console.log("Hello");
      sleep(2000).then(() => { console.log("World!"); });
  
  // console.log(results)
  }


readXlsx()
```

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fundamental concept in modern JavaScript is something called a `promise`, which you can read more about [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/guide-promises-node-js/). This background is important for you to understand the answers to your questions.

1. There are two ways of doing this, using `.then()` (like you are), or using `await`. I find `await` easier to understand when thinking about promises (and it fits a bit better into the structure of what you're doing), and you can read about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_async.asp). Below is the same code, using `await` and `async` instead:

```js
const readXlsxFile = require("read-excel-file/node");
const fs = require('fs')
// const results = [];
var results = [];
let maxRow

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

// V - Notice that this is an "async" function
async function readXlsx() {
  const rows = await readXlsxFile('./myfile.xlsx')
  results.push(rows)

  const maxRow = rows.length

  for (var nRow = 1; nRow < maxRow - 1; nRow++) {
    console.log(nRow)
    console.log()
    console.log(results[0][nRow][1])
    console.log(results[0][nRow][2])
    console.log('---')
  }
}
```

because we are now `await`ing the result of the `readXlsxFile` function, the code will not continue before `readXlsxFile` is finished. This way, if you refer to the function in another area, `results` will be properly defined:

```
// ... this is a continuation of your code
async function logMyResults() {
  await readXlsx()

  // This will not run until readXlsx() is done, since it's being `await`ed
  console.log(results)
}
```

while you should probably just be returning `results` instead, that is how it would work in the way you currently have everything set up.

2. I think you were misunderstanding how `.then()` works. `.then()` is how you would run code after a promise finishes. The problem is that only the code within the function you provide to `.then()` will be run after the promise is done, and everything else outside of it will continue running without waiting. Using the same `async/await` code above, you can now use `sleep` as intended:

```js
async function readXlsx() {
  const rows = await readXlsxFile('./myfile.xlsx')
  results.push(rows)

  const maxRow = rows.length

  for (var nRow = 1; nRow < maxRow - 1; nRow++) {
    console.log(nRow)
    console.log()
    console.log(results[0][nRow][1])
    console.log(results[0][nRow][2])
    console.log('---')
    
    await sleep(1000)
  }
}
```

which properly blocks execution within the entire function.

3. I don't know what error you got, so I have no way of knowing, but it is probably because, at that time, `readXlsx` was not an async function, and you can only call `.then()` on the results of an async function (AKA: a promise)